# Coding Efficiency in a Branching Storyline

Tags: python

I've been a python student for the past 3 months and I'm trying to work on an assignment with the following requirements.

You must create a multiple text adventure with 4 levels.

Each choice made must lead to 3 unique choices in the next level.

This means the assignment requires **3 choices in level 1**, **9 choices in level 2**, **27 choices in level 3**, and **81 choices in level 4**. Being new to python I'm finding it rough to make this both efficient, organized, and work correctly.

Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
while adventure_running:  # the entire branch of choices.. there might be an easier way to do this but I couldn't figure it out
    print_situation('1')
    answer = input().upper()
    if answer == 'A':
        print_situation('2_A')
        answer = input().upper()
        if answer == 'A':
            print_situation('3_A1')
            answer = input().upper()
            if answer == 'A':
                print_situation('4_A1_A1')
                answer = input().upper()
                if answer == 'A':
                    print("FINAL STATEMENT")
                    adventure_running = False
                    answer = 'D'  # I set the answer value to D at the end so the program doesn't save the value throughout multiple runs
```

The above code is repeated appropriately to accommodate for all 120 choices.

The print_situation function looks at a dictionary and finds the prompt and choices associated with it.

My main issue with this is that if the user enters incorrect input it restarts the entire text adventure rather than printing the current situation again.

I understand that this is probably incredibly inefficient so I would love to hear any suggestions for improvements along with the above concern.

**Is there any way to do this without object oriented programming?**

Comment: dictionaries are your friends, or classes and sub classes representing levels

Comment: You have > 100 nested `if`s?

Comment: Yeah. It's a lot of if statements and my class hasn't learned about classes or object oriented programming in python yet..

Answer (score 1):

You could use a state machine:

```
state = '1'   
table = {'1':{'A':'2_A'}, '2_A':{'A':'3_A1'}, 
         '3_A1':{'A':'4_A1_A1'}, '4_A1_A1':{'A':'done'}}

while True:
     print_situation(state)
     if state == 'done':
         break
     state = table[state][input().upper()]
```

This prints the situation. Check if we are in a done state. Otherwise transitions via the lookup table.

Note that if you have as you say:

> 3 choices in level 1, 9 choices in level 2, 27 choices in level 3, and 81 choices in level 4.

You have:

```
>>> 1+3+3*9+3*9*27+3*9*27*81
59809
```

states.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why there is object oriented programming. You need classes for Choice, Answer and another for Level.Then construct objects.

Comment: Is there any way to complete the assignment without OOP? Our class hasn't learned anything about it yet..

Comment: Well its a OOP problem, if you haven't learned it yet then try to do it using dictionary. A nested dictionary of levels, choices and probably answers.

Comment: I have a dictionary of every prompt and choice which the print_situation function reads and uses. How could I set up the dictionary to actually run the game?